# selenium Test case for facebook login and logout

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, selenium-ide

Scenario is to Login to facebook account and then logout. I tried using xpath className and id. But everytime it shows error as ElementNotfound or element not visible. Later I Checked it using SELENIUM IDE and got this xpath for the LOGOUT link. But still the error persists. Kindly help me.

```java
public class FacebookLogin {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/");
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        WebElement username = driver.findElement(By.id("email"));
        WebElement password = driver.findElement(By.id("pass"));
        WebElement Login = driver.findElement(By.id("u_0_v"));
        username.sendKeys("myusername@xyz.com");
        password.sendKeys("mypassword");
        Login.click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        //driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        WebElement navigationclick = driver.findElement(By.id("logoutMenu"));
        WebElement logout = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='u_d_1']/div/div/div/div/div/ul/li[12]/a/span/span"));
        navigationclick.click();
        if(logout.isEnabled() && logout.isDisplayed()) {
            logout.click();
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Element not found");
        }

    }

}
```

HTML CODE FOR LOG OUT 
    
    
   
    
    
    
    
    Log Out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code solved the issue for Logout from Facebook:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='userNavigationLabel']")).click();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[12]/a/span/span")).click();
```

Comment: `.implicitlyWait()` doesn't actually wait... it just sets the default wait. Please read [the docs](https://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.Timeouts.html).

Comment: Please don't forget to mark this as the answer once you can.

Comment: Having static value in the xpath may not always work. In this case, it is using like `//li[12]`. You may need something more generic and yet unique `location identifier`

Answer (score 1):

Adding below simple code:

```
    package open_website;

    import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
    import org.openqa.selenium.By;
    import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;




        public class Open_website_1
       {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String expath = "D:\\Eclipse\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe";

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\Eclipse\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");

        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();



        driver.get("http:\\www.facebook.com");


        WebElement element1 = driver.findElement(By.id("email"));
        element1.sendKeys("patil_y7@yahoo.com");

        WebElement element2 = driver.findElement(By.id("pass"));
        element2.sendKeys("pa$$word123");

        WebElement element3 = driver.findElement(By.id("u_0_q"));
        element3.click();

        System.out.println("Login");




        WebElement lstitem=driver.findElement(By.id("userNavigationLabel"));
        lstitem.click();

        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60,TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Log Out")).click();

        System.out.println("Log out");




    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

WORKING:

```
public class FacebookLogin {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException 

    {
        String exePath = "C:\\\\Users\\Diganta\\Desktop\\Workspace\\Library\\chromedriver.exe";
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", exePath);

        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

        driver.get("https://www.facebook.com");
        System.out.println("Successfully opened the website");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.findElement(By.id("email")).sendKeys("Enter the USERNAME");
        driver.findElement(By.id("pass")).sendKeys("Enter the PASSWORD");
        driver.findElement(By.id("u_0_r")).click();
        System.out.println("Successfully logged in");
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        driver.findElement(By.id("userNavigationLabel")).click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Log out")).click();
        System.out.println("Successfully logged out");

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavascriptExecutor to click on logout after login to system

```
WebElement logout=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='u_d_1']/div/div/div/div/div/ul/li[12]/a/span/span"));
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", logout);
```

Get back to me if you are still facing problem

Comment: I am still getting the same error for the above code. I am attaching the html code '<span>
<span class="_54nh">
<form id="u_7_2" class="_w0d" onsubmit="return window.Event && Event.__inlineSubmit && Event.__inlineSubmit(this,event)" method="post" action="https://www.facebook.com/logout.php">
<input type="hidden" autocomplete="off" value="AQGXa0awYmNO" name="fb_dtsg">
<input type="hidden" value="mb" name="ref" autocomplete="off">
<input type="hidden" value="AffbnzchAqOMeSO9" name="h" autocomplete="off">
</form>
Log Out
</span>
</span>'

Comment: can please send me the error which you are getting on console

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//span[contains(.,'Log Out')]"}
Command duration or timeout: 74 milliseconds

Comment: I have edited the xpath in my answer as you have mentioned in the question. Please try again and let me know. Actually xpath of facebook changing time to time and user to user for me xpath is .//*[@id='u_d_7']/div/div/div[1]/div/div/ul/li[18]/a/span/span

Comment: Thank you for your efforts @Shubham Jain , as you mentioned, the xpath is changing everytime I check for logout.  I have posted my solution, if any better solutions It would be great to learn and understand it.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is looking for a Selenium IDE solution, or wishes to tweak the above solution here is what I use, along with the goto extension and defined values for FacebookUserName and FacebookPassword

Notice that I first do a check if the user is logged in - if they are logged in I logout first, if not I login only.

```
<tr>
<td>open</td>
<td>https://www.facebook.com</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>storeElementPresent</td>
<td>id=userNavigationLabel</td>
<td>LoggedIn</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>gotoIf</td>
<td>'${LoggedIn}' != false</td>
<td>LoggedIn</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>click</td>
<td>id=userNavigationLabel</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>click</td>
<td>//span[text()='Log Out']</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>label</td>
<td>LoggedIn</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>type</td>
<td>id=email</td>
<td>${FacebookUserName}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>type</td>
<td>id=pass</td>
<td>${FacebookPassword}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>click</td>
<td>//input[@value='Log In']</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy to solve. 
Instead of using

`click()`

action *use*

`submit()`

since logout is in the form.

Answer (score 0):

Python code for facebook logout using selenium

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("._w0d[action='https://www.facebook.com/logout.php']").submit()
```

Using the CSS selector method, select the logout element using the class "._w0d" and attribute for action="https://www.facebook.com/logout.php".
This being a form, should be submitted, thus use the "submit" method.

Answer (score -1):

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;


public class FbLoginLogout {

 public static void main(String [] args) throws InterruptedException

 {
     WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
     driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/login.php");
     driver.manage().window().maximize();
     driver.findElement(By.id("email")).sendKeys("************");
     WebElement pass = driver.findElement(By.id("pass"));
     pass.clear();
     pass.sendKeys("*********");
     pass.submit();
     System.out.println("Logged in Successfully.......");
     //Logout
     driver.findElement(By.id("userNavigationLabel")).click();
     Thread.sleep(5000);
     driver.findElement(By.linkText("Log Out")).click();
     System.out.println("Logged Out Successfully!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
     String pagetitle = driver.getTitle();
     System.out.println(pagetitle);

  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

code for facebook loging and logout : (working)

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class my_DemoTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "Driver Path\\geckodriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/");
        driver.findElement(By.id("email")).sendKeys("abcd@gmail.com");
        driver.findElement(By.id("pass")).sendKeys("abcd_password");
        driver.findElement(By.id("loginbutton")).click();
        System.out.println("Login");
        Thread.sleep(6000);
        driver.findElement(By.id("userNavigationLabel")).click();
        Thread.sleep(4000);
        driver.findElement(By.linkText("Log out")).click();
        System.out.println("Logout successfully");
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain how your solution differs from OPs code and why this is the solution.